# Making a scrollable div which doesn't scroll the rest of the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

Should be simple but I can't work it out.

I have two panes on my webpage. I want both to be independently scrollable:

```
<body>
   <div id="sidebar"> ... lots of content ... </div>
   <div id="container"> ... lots of content ... </div>
</body>

#sidebar{
    width:200px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urp981s6/2/embedded/result/). Notice how when you scroll to the bottom in the black sidebar, and keep scrolling, the body starts to scroll? That's what I want to avoid. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure? This is not happening on my browser. I´m using FireFox

Comment: Really? In Chrome it definitely is, perhaps it's a Chrome-only quirk...

Comment: I would recommend you use [niceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following updated CSS.  Here I have set 200px height after that it will add scroll bar for **#sidebar** div.

```
#sidebar{
    width:200px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:200px;

}
```

Hope it may help.!!

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
overflow-y : hidden 
}
```

helps you if you don't want body to be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

This is working if I understood your problem correctly. Just making overflow:hidden when mouse is over sidebar div.

```
 #sidebar:hover + #container{
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: some_value; // your window height
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You´re right. In Chrome it happens.
Maybe some jQuery?

```
$("#sidebar").focus(function(){
    $('body').css("overflowY","hidden");
});
$("#sidebar").blur(function(){
    $('body').css("overflowY","scroll"); 
});
```

Add `tabindex="-1"` to sidebar to get this working

[Actually Working](https://jsfiddle.net/UrielUVD/uL1uxz61/1/)

Comment: shouldn't be `overflow-y` ?